# child is not fully visible inside an "overflow-x: visible" parent

Tags: html, css

two questions in the example below:

- why `grida` is not centered horizontally -`margin: 0 auto`
- why `cins` is not fully visible - parent is `overflow-x:visible`

```css
.grida{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns:99px 140px 99px;
margin:0 auto;
background:lightblue;
}

.gridab{
overflow-y:scroll;
}

.gridaa, .gridac{
height:150vh; overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:visible;
background:silver;
position:relative;
}
.cins{
position:absolute;
right:-54px; top:25px; width: 200px;
height:70vh; background:orange;

}
```

```html
<div class='grida'>
<div class='gridaa'></div>
<div class='gridab'></div>
<div class='gridac'>
<div class='cins'></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why `grida` is not centered horizontally -`margin: 0 auto`

`grida` is the full viewport width, so centering it horizontally within the viewport is sort of nonsensical.

> why slide is not fully visible - parent is `overflow-x:visible`

The horizontal overflow doesn't work because the vertical overflow is `scroll`. [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x#values), for `overflow-x`:

> If overflow-y is hidden, scroll or auto and this property is visible, it will implicitly compute to auto.

If you inspect the element in the browser dev tools and look at the computed style you'll see that `overflow-x` has resolved to `auto`, and `auto` gives you a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: how grid can be larger than sum of its columns ?

Comment: A `display: grid` element "behaves like a block element and lays out its content according to the grid model". Did you want `display: inline-grid`?

Comment: seems `inline-grid` is a solution for the first part. Second - how to see `cins` fully i.e. inside and both outsite parts regarding its parent ?

Answer (score 1):

**why grida is not centered horizontally -margin: 0 auto**

*It is centered. But it takes up the whole width, setting the width to 338px (99px+140px+99px) you see that it is centered.*

**why slide is not fully visible - parent is overflow-x:visible**

*You are using a grid layout, and you have defined exact width for 3 columns of `99px 140px 99px`. Those dimensions are strictly respected. Also the `.cins` element is positioned as `absolute` and the parent would not detect the width of the contained element anyway (it works like this).*

```css
.grida {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 99px 140px 99px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  background-color: red;
  width: 338px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.gridaa,
.gridac {
  height: 150vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: visible;
  background: silver;
  position: relative;
}

.cins {
  position: absolute;
  display:inline-block;
  right: -54px;
  top: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 70vh;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class='grida'>
  <div style="background-color:pink">99px</div>
  <div style="background-color:yellow">140px</div>
  <div style="background-color:green">99px</div>
</div>
<div class='grida'>
  <div class='gridaa'></div>
  <div class='gridab'></div>
  <div class='gridac'>
    <div class='cins'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so how can I see `cins` fully, i.e. inside and outside parts regarding its parent ?

Comment: @provance Simply remove `/*overflow-y: scroll;*/` from `.gridac`. [Check on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/px6rmc7g/)